# Удаление обработчика

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка, dom

Здравствуйте! Имеется четыре блока, при нажатии на которые должны добавляться обработчики:

```
$('#main td.display').click(function(){
$(this).scroll();
});
```

Плагин scroll лежит в отдельном файле и выглядит так (опущены не существенные детали  и полное содержание функций):

```
jQuery.fn.display_scroll= function(type){
window.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheel, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheel, false);
//window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
function wheel(event)
{
console.log('catch');
}
};
```

При нажатии обработчики добавляются, но не удаляются, кол-во обработчиков в конце будет очень большим и меня это беспокоит. Также интересно, как удалить закоментированный обработчик (для хрома). Можно ли вообще эти обработчики повесить напрямую к элементу (у меня не получилось)? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В jQuery уже есть метод [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Поэтому, может работать не корректно.

Comment: Сменил название, ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем отходить от jQuery стиля кодинга на нативный?

```
jQuery.fn.display_scroll= function(func){
    $(window).unbind('scroll').on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('catch');
    });
};
```

Comment: Мне нужно поймать именно момент прокрутки колеса, а не прокрутки элемента. Я стилизую полосу прокрутки и у родительского элемента она отсутсвует (overflow: hidden;)

Comment: @Indev если вы вынесите функцию wheel за пределы плагина, то обработчик будет удаляться. Уверен, можно сделать еще красивее.

Comment: Воооот! Спасибо, это и требовалось.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с колесом, нужно перехватить минимум два события: mousewheel, DomMouseScroll
или воспользоваться замечательным расширением [jquery.mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).

P.S. Если я правильно понял из коментов, вы хотите стилизовать scrollbar, если это так, то не трате зря время, нитивный в всё равно будет удобней и быстрей, либо воспользуйтесь библиотекой [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html).